# On uninstall hybrid mobile app can trigger ajax call?

Tags: javascript, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

A mobile app created using HTML, CSS and javascript.

APK & IPA generated using Cordova & Xcode with developer certificates. And the app can install now on mobile devices.

Is there any way to call/trigger ajax call to the server on our app uninstall from mobile devices.

Kindly guide me to achieve the functionality.